# Place button next to framelayout

Tags: android

I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_imageview_pattern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_button_take_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_take_photo" />
```

Unfortunately this isnt working. The FrameLayout is hiding the button because the FrameLayout is taking the whole Screen. I want a button next to the FrameLayout. How can i achiev that?

Comment: set layout_height of FrameLayout to wrap_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_imageview_pattern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_button_take_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_take_photo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

add in frameLayout and in Button:

```
android:layout_weight = "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

just add Weight in FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_camera_preview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_camera_preview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_above="@recipe_fragment_button_take_photo"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_imageview_pattern"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />

  </FrameLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/recipe_fragment_button_take_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/button_take_photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```